# Launching app in foreground with Qt under MacOS X

Tags: macos, qt

I am having problems with a little Qt 5.0.1 program under Mac OS X 10.8.
(I have not tested any other platforms yet.)

I am launching an external Mac OS X program with this line of code:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fullpath));
```

Where `fullpath` contains a path to an application like:

```
/Users/schube/QTWorkspace/HelloWorld-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_clang_64bit-Debug/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../Aptus.app
```

(`Aptus.app` is a random app I've chosen, could be any app. I placed it in this path for testing purposes).

The application starts correctly but always in *background*; or at least, behind a Finder window. Really strange!

How can I force the new launched app to be sent to the *foreground*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QProcess instead, but make sure that rather than using the path to the executable as the object to run, pass it to the open command as an argument. Something like this: -

```
QString cmd = QString("open %1").arg(fullpath); // may need QUrl::fromLocalFile(fullpath)
QProcess::startDetached(cmd);
```

Without using 'open', it will also open up behind other applications.

Note that you could also use the execute function, if you want to wait for the program to finish.

Also, with the open command, I think you only need to pass the path to the app bundle, rather than full path to its executable in Contents/MacOS. Either should work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a feature of the Mac OSX's window manager so that it does not steal focus.

You might need to alter your application to minimize.